# How to exit `read` Bash builtin by pressing the Esc key?

Tags: bash

How to exit `read` builtin by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>?

Example snippet that *doesn't* react to <kbd>Esc</kbd>:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Quit - press key Esc"
echo "Enter name :"
read
```

Comment: I don't know if this is the best solution, but you could compare with escape printed by echo `read <press ESC then ENTER>;[ "$REPLY" = "$(echo -e '\033')" ] && echo ESC`

Comment: syntax error near unexpected token `;'`read <press ESC then ENTER>;[ "$REPLY" = "$(echo -e '\033')" ] && echo ESC'

Comment: Excuse me I wasn't clear, <press esc then enter> is your actions. Test this and if it works as you want I will post as answer `read;[ "$REPLY" = "$(echo -e '\033')" ] && echo ESC`.

Answer (score 1):

In Bash `read -e` uses readline. It will exit with exit status `1` when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> is the only input. So if we managed to make <kbd>Esc</kbd> trigger `kill-whole-line` and then send `\C-d`, it should do the trick.

I cannot make a sole keystroke do these two things in sequence. I can, however, bind `kill-whole-line` to another keystroke and make <kbd>Esc</kbd> send the keystroke and `\C-d`:

```
set -o emacs
bind '"\C-w": kill-whole-line'
bind '"\e": "\C-w\C-d"'
read -e
```

If you want `read` to return exit status `0` after <kbd>Esc</kbd>, the second binding should be:

```
bind '"\e": "\C-w\C-j"'
```

Or you can choose to pass some specific string as input:

```
bind '"\e": "\C-w---interrupted---\C-j"'
```

Or make <kbd>Esc</kbd> simply act like <kbd>Enter</kbd> (accept the input):

```
bind '"\e": "\C-j"'    # no prior \C-w binding required for this
```

---

Note that multiple fast <kbd>Esc</kbd> strokes [are more than just few escapes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/391927/108618). Some people tend to rapidly press <kbd>Esc</kbd> few times to abort fast. For this reason you may want to bind `"\e\e"` to the same string as `"\e"`.

And if there are few such strokes "left" after `read -e` exits, they will be "utilized" later. You probably don't want this, so discard excessive characters from stdin with this command:

```
read -st 0.1 -n 1000000
```

If you run it just after the first `read`, consider longer timeout to catch all strokes of <kbd>Esc</kbd>, plus a prior message that would make impatient user stop stroking the key.

---

The whole script may look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o emacs
bind '"\C-w": kill-whole-line'
bind '"\e": "\C-w\C-d"'
bind '"\e\e": "\C-w\C-d"'
IFS= read -rep "Enter name (ESC to exit): " || {
  printf '\nAborting\n'
  read -st 1 -n 1000000
  exit 1
}
printf 'The input was %s\n' "$REPLY"
```

The script (unless sourced) runs in its own shell so these bindings won't affect the shell you invoke it from. There is no need to unbind, unless the script itself continues and at some point the bindings interfere with something.